# Filtering by PHP

Tags: php, filter

I have a $data at a column1 shows me:

"AAA123"
"ABC1234"
"ABD123"
"BAC12"
"CAB123"
"DA125"
and so on..

I would like to show $data starting with only "AB" which shows me at column1 like :

"ABC1234"
"ABD123"

not the others but also other rows and columns related to "ABC1234" and "ABD123"

---

Thanx in advance.

[Sample structure http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/8994/34310422.jpg](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/8994/34310422.jpg)

Comment: What's `$data`'s type? An array of strings? Is `$data` the result of an SQL query?

Comment: no i get $data from txt with split

Comment: So what's `$data`s type? An array of strings? An array of arrays? If the latter, what's the structure of the inner arrays?

Comment: Screenshots of code aren't nearly as useful as code itself. You should also pick an indent style (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and use it. I personally recommend the 1TBS.

Comment: outis thank you indeed also others for this kind concern. Actually i dont know how to write this things but only edit as i needed. I think i need to study much more coding then editing.

Answer (score 3):

If `$data` is an array of strings, you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter).

PHP 5.3 or later:

```
$AB = array_filter($data, function($str) {
    return 'AB' == substr($str, 0, 2);
});
```

before PHP 5.3:

```
$AB = array_filter($data, 
                   create_function('$str', 
                                   'return "AB" == substr($str, 0, 2);'
                  )               );
```

Or:

```
function create_prefix_tester($prefix) {
    return create_function('$str', 
                  "return '$prefix' == substr(\$str, 0, " . strlen($prefix) . ');'
                  );
}
$AB = array_filter($data, create_prefix_tester('AB'));
```

Or you could use a loop:

```
foreach ($data as $str) {
    if ('AB' ==  substr($str, 0, 2)) {
      // do stuff
      ...
    }
}
```

### Edit

From the sample code, it looks like you'll want the loop:

```
while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets($fp))) {
    $row = explode('|', $line); // split() is deprecated
    if ('AB' == substr($row[0], 0, 2)) {
        switch($sortby) {
        case 'schools': // fallthru
        default:
            $sortValue = $row[0];
            break;
        case 'dates':
            $sortValue = $row[1];
            break;
        case 'times':
            $sortValue = $row[2];
            break;
        }
        array_unshift($row, $sortValue);
        $table[] = $row;
    }
}
```

or:

```
function cmp_schools($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
}
function cmp_dates($a, $b) {
    return $a['datestamp'] - $b['datestamp'];
}
function cmp_times($a, $b) {
    return $a['timestamp'] - $b['timestamp'];
}
while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets($fp))) {
    $row = explode('|', $line); // split() is deprecated
    if ('AB' == substr($row[0], 0, 2)) {
        $when = strtotime($row[1] + ' ' + $row[2]);
        $row['timestamp'] = $when % (60*60*24);
        $row['datestamp'] = $when - $row['timestamp'];
        $table[] = $row;
    }
}
usort($table, 'cmp_' + $sortby);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use `substr()`, as in the following snippet:

```
if (substr($str, 0, 2) == 'AB') {
  // The string is right.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strpos` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), like

```
if (strpos($my_string, "AB") === 0) {
  <do stuff>
}
```

Be very sure to use `===` instead of `==`, because if "AB" is not found then the function will return false, which will equate to 0 using `==`.

Comment: i think this one is the most close reply. Now i have the exact number of rows regarding my query -which means "strpos" is working- , but whole table (rows and columns) turns empty. Any idea ?